# Replace a condition with Bool TryParse() in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Im trying to replace the following with bool TryParse();

```cs
result = table1.Columns.Contains("data1") ?
         (table1.Rows[0]["data1"].ToString().ToLower().Equals("true") ? true : false) :
         result;
```

problem is, if there is no "data1" , it returns as false(which actually should be null), else true. I want the " result" to be assigned as null if there is no data1.

Comment: Please show an example of possible input and expected output. There are multiple situations where it's not clear what you expect. There could be the `data1` column missing, there could be no rows in that table, the data1 column could contain an invalid value. What would you expect in each of these situations?

Comment: When you say "there is no 'data' do you mean no column or the column contains NULL? Please be explicit. Note that, as this is a `DataTable`, there should never be a C# `null` there at all. If you're getting data from the database then a NULL value will be represented by `DBNull.Value` and `DBNull.ToString` returns `string.Empty`. That is a `string` that is not equal to "true", so you get `false`.

Comment: Why not using the `bool.TryParse` directly?

Comment: What do you mean by "return"? There is no function there to return. Are you saying that you want to replace `table1.Rows[0]["data1"].ToString().ToLower().Equals("true") ? true : false` with an expression that evaluates to `null` if the `data1` column contains NULL?

Answer (score 5):

EDIT:

I've left my original answer intact but I think I misinterpreted something. Assuming that the `data1` column is nullable and you want a NULL field, which actually contain `DBNull.Value`, to produce a C# `null`, then you can do this:

```cs
table1.Rows[0].IsNull("data1")
    ? (bool?)null
    : bool.TryParse(table1.Rows[0].Field<string>("data1"), out var data1) && data1
```

That will check for NULL first and then parse the `string` if there is one. Of course, if you want the value to be able to be `null`, the data type is now `bool?` rather than `bool`.

ORIGINAL:

You can declare a variable inline when passing an `out` argument so you can test a Boolean `string` like this:

```cs
if (bool.TryParse(text, out var flag) && flag)
```

`TryParse` will return `true` if `text` is parsed successfully and then `flag` will either be `true` or `false`. That means that this:

```cs
table1.Rows[0]["data1"].ToString().ToLower().Equals("true") ? true : false
```

would become this:

```cs
bool.TryParse(table1.Rows[0]["data1"].ToString(), out var data1) && data1
```

Note that, if the input fails to parse, the first expression will be `false` so the whole thing will be `false`. If the input parses successfully, the whole thing has the same value as the second expression.

I should mention that such inline declarations have not always been possible but, if anyone is using a version of C# old enough that it's not, they probably ought to upgrade.

Comment: im not getting it, could you please elaborate

Comment: And how is this returnin `null` like requiredd by Op?

Comment: @Fildor, there will be no exception because a database null is represented by `DBNull.Value` and `DBNull.ToString` returns `string.Empty`. Stiull, I think I may have misunderstood the question regardless. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Oh, jep that's true. Still, you wouldn't be able to distinguish between the value not being set or being false ... Will delete my answer, if you choose to make yours behave as expected by OP.

Comment: @derpirscher, I believe I have now addressed that.

Comment: Just one remark to OP: If you do like this, you will lose the information if the value couldn't be parsed. I mean: If the field contained "Frank", that would resolve to `false` without you being able to realize that the field did not actually contain a non-bool. _But I guess, that's not an issue in your scenario?_

Comment: @Freshernoob, I've updated my answer to (I think) properly address your question. Does it make sense now?

Comment: @Fildor, with respect to data that was present but could not be parsed, I guess the alternative would be to treat that as though it was not present. In that case you could do this: `table1.Rows[0].IsNull("data1") || !bool.TryParse(table1.Rows[0].Field<string>("data1"), out var data1) ? (bool?)null : data1`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes, I think this would be a non-issue here. Just wanted to make OP _aware_ of that. _I guess_ that behavior is totally fine, though.